# File.mkdirs() returns false even with permissions

Tags: java, android, file, makefile, mkdir

I've got the following code:

```
private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 1001;
private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};

public String getBatchDirectoryName() {
    String app_folder_path = "";
    

    if(allPermissionsGranted()){
        Log.e("i enter this code","!");
        app_folder_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/images";
        File dir = new File(app_folder_path);
        if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) { //both are false but why?
            Log.e("failed to create:",app_folder_path); ///returns: storage/emulated/0/images
        }

    }else{
        app_folder_path = "fail"; // i DONT enter this code t
    }
    return app_folder_path;
}

private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){

    for(String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am trying to save a image so I use the function `getBatchDirectoryName()` to create a directory if it does not exsist,or else returning the exsisting directory.

The issue is that, the directory does not exsist I cant create it for some reason. Both functions `exists` and `mkdirs` return false.
What can the cause be? I check before If I have the permission for writing files.

Comment: That code will not work on Android 11+ once your `targetSdkVersion` rises to `30`. You cannot create directories in arbitrary locations anymore. Please consider using the Storage Access Framework and allow the user to choose where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) your app should put the user's content.

Comment: `app_folder_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/images";`
` Change to `app_folder_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/images";` and it will work on Android 11. For Android you can use your old code if you request legacy external storage in manifest.

Comment: I don't think the `makefile` tag means what you think it means :).  It should be removed from this question IMO.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for you info. I will try it when I get home if it works and let u know

Comment: @blackapps thanks for you info. I will try it when I get home if it works and let u know